# How to avoid stackoverflow exception in multiple recursion?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to make custom OpenApiSchema generator.

How it works:

This is example api:

```
[ApiCommands]                 
abstract public class Commands
{
    [ApiArgument( typeof( SubjectsListArguments ), isOptional: true )]
    [ApiReturn( typeof( SubjectsListResponse ) )]                     
    [Title]                                                           
    [Description]                                                     
    public const string SubjectsList = "subjects_list";               
}
```

So ApiArgument, ApiReturn represent DTOs. All I need is to create OpenApiSchema by this model. Let's see code for getting `IDictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>`:

```
private IDictionary<string, OpenApiSchema> GenerateProperties(Type arguments)
{                                                                              
    var properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>();                  
                                                                              
    GeneratePropertiesRecursive(arguments, properties);                      
                                                                               
    return properties;                                                         
}
```

```
private void GeneratePropertiesRecursive(                                                                        
    Type type,                                                                                                   
    IDictionary<string, OpenApiSchema> properties)                                                              
{                                                                                                                
    if (type == null) return;                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                 
    var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();                                                                    
                                                                                                                 
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)                                                                
    {                                                                                                            
        var attributeValue = propertyInfo                                                                        
            .GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();                                                        
                                                                                                                 
        if (attributeValue == null)                                                                            
            continue;                                                                                            
                                                                                                                 
        var propertyName = attributeValue.PropertyName;                                                          
        var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;                                                            
                                                                                                                 
        var propertySchema = new OpenApiSchema();                                                                
                                                                                                                 
        if (propertyType.IsClass && !_excludedTypes.Contains(propertyType))                                                        
        {                                                                                                        
            if (ImplementsEnumerableTypes(propertyType, out var genericTypes))                               
            {                                                                                                    
                var itemsSchema = new OpenApiSchema();                                                           
                                                                                                                 
                foreach (var genericType in genericTypes)                                                      
                {                                                                                                
                    if (_excludedTypes.Contains(genericType))                                                
                    {                                                                                            
                        itemsSchema = genericType.MapTypeToOpenApiType(propertySchema);                        
                        break;                                                                                   
                    }                                                                                            
                                                                                                                 
                    GeneratePropertiesRecursive(genericType, itemsSchema.Properties);                          
                }                                                                                                
                                                                                                                 
                propertySchema.Type = "array";                                                                   
                propertySchema.Items = itemsSchema;                                                              
                                                                                                                 
                properties.Add(propertyName, propertySchema);                                                  
                continue;                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                 
            GeneratePropertiesRecursive(propertyType, propertySchema.Properties);                              
        }                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                 
        if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(OptionalValue<>))    
        {                                                                                                        
            var genericType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];                                           
                                                                                                                 
            GeneratePropertiesRecursive(genericType, propertySchema.Properties);                               
                                                                                                                 
            propertyType = genericType;                                                                          
        }                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                 
        if (IsNullableType(propertyType, out var nullableType))                                              
            propertyType = nullableType;                                                                         
                                                                                                                 
        if (propertyType.IsEnum)                                                                                
        {                                                                                                        
            var types = propertyType.GetOpenApiTypesFromEnumPropertyType();                                      
                                                                                                                 
            propertySchema.Type = "string";                                                                      
            propertySchema.Enum = types;                                                                         
                                                                                                                 
            properties.Add( propertyName, propertySchema );                                                      
            continue;                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                 
        propertySchema = propertyType.MapTypeToOpenApiType(propertySchema);                                    
                                                                                                                 
        properties.Add(propertyName, propertySchema);                                                          
    }                                                                                                            
}
```

I have three problems:

1. I can generate OpenApiSchema for one type several times, I don't control this, and I don't understand how to do it..
2. We can have cycle in dto, thats why stackoverflow exception. For example: we have `SubjectDto` and `DepartmentDto`. `SubjectDto` has reference to `DepartmentDto` and `DepartmentDto` has reference to `SubjectDto`
3. It is really hard to read....

Also we can add references:

```
Schema = new OpenApiSchema
{
   Reference = new OpenApiReference
   {
       Id = $"{name}_response",
       Type = ReferenceType.Schema
   }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed on-topic for StackOverflow :-)

Comment: _"How to avoid stackoverflow exception in multiple recursion?"_ => avoid recursion.

Comment: you can't solve this problem without recursion

Comment: Any recursive code can be refactored to an iteration-based code.

Comment: _"you can't solve this problem without recursion"_ citation needed.

Comment: _"3. It is really hard to read...."_ - yes. Because you tried to stuff _everything_ into one what we call "eierlegende Wollmilchsau" in Germany. (literally "pig that gives you milk, wool and eggs") You need to break out sub-problems and solve those separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can help with your second problem and, by extension, your third...

Generally you can flatten a recursive method by using a `Stack` or a `Queue` (choose one depending on whether you'd rather your algorithm be width-first or depth-first, see below):

1. Put the parameters for your first call to the recursive method on the stack/queue
2. Call your method inside a loop which pops the "first" set of parameters
3. Instead of recursively calling  back into the method, push the parameters onto the stack/queue for the next iteration of the loop to pop
4. Loop until there is no more iterations to perform

This approach may still lead to memory issues, especially where pushing inside a `foreach`, but will be much more efficient than pushing a whole new frame onto The Stack.

Example:

```cs
class RecursiveStructure
{
    public required string Name { get; init; }
    public required IEnumerable<RecursiveStructure> Children { get; init; }  
}

void MethodRecursion(RecursiveStructure data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"MR {data.Name}");
    foreach (var child in data.Children)
        MethodRecursion(child);
}

void QueueRecursion(RecursiveStructure data)
{
    var queue = new Queue<RecursiveStructure>();
    queue.Enqueue(data);
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out var current))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"QR {current.Name}");
        foreach (var child in current.Children)
            queue.Enqueue(child);
    }
}

void StackRecursion(RecursiveStructure data)
{
    var stack = new Stack<RecursiveStructure>();
    stack.Push(data);
    while (stack.TryPop(out var current))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SR {current.Name}");
        foreach (var child in current.Children.Reverse()) // NB we need to reverse child order or they'll be popped backwards
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

Note that the Stack and Method recursion approaches lead to the same depth-first output, while the Queue approach leads to a width-first output.

Here's some fiddles you can play with based on the above example:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/MOEFTg
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEZDIi

Comment: Fiddles are fine but you should consider including code as text to showcase your approach. That way the answer does not depend on outside resources (dead links are a notorious thing on SO) that much (which is preferred). Self-contained question, self-contained answers, basically. Fiddles are "bonus".

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback @Fildor-standswithMods, I've updated the answer to make it more self-contained.